# How to make a separate table for separate student in the view file

Tags: php, html

I have students in database and their fee table. i am getting all fee's of students submitted within two dates. Currently i am showing each result in a row. some student have multiple records as they have submitted multiple fee's inbetween those days. But i want to show each same student's data in seperate table.

[This is Current Design Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJctX.png)

[I want these tables in design Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XT6Sa.png)

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Voucher</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Net Amount</th>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Issue Date</th>
      <th>Due Date</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php 
      $paidcount = 0;
      $unpaidcount = 0;
      $unpaidamount = 0;
      $totalsum = 0;
      $payablesum = 0;
      $count = 1; 
      foreach ($this->vouchers as $key => $voucher) {  ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $count++; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $voucher['id']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo ucwords($voucher['name']); ?></td>
          <td>
            <?php
              $totalsum+=$voucher['total'];
              echo $voucher['total'];
            ?>                            
           </td>
           <td>
             <?php
               $payablesum+=$voucher['payable'];
               echo $voucher['payable'];
             ?>            
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $voucher['id_month'], 10)); ?>
            </td>
            <td><?php echo $voucher['issue_date']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $voucher['due_date']; ?></td>
            <td>
              <?php if($voucher['paid']==1) {
                $paidcount+=$voucher['paid'];
                echo "Paid";
                } else {
                  $unpaidamount = $voucher['payable'];
                  $unpaidcount++;
                  echo "Pending";
                } ?>
              </td>
              <td class="text-center">
                <a href="<?php echo SITEURL."vouchersinfo/?action=voucherDetails&id_voucher=".$voucher['id']; ?>" title="View Voucher Details"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
             <?php } ?>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2"><strong>Total Vouchers: </strong><?php echo --$count; ?>
              </td>
              <td colspan="1"><strong>Received: </strong><?php echo $paidcount; ?>
              </td>
              <td colspan="1"><strong>Unpaid: </strong><?php echo $unpaidcount; ?>
              </td>
              <td colspan="2"><strong>Total Amount: </strong><?php echo $totalsum; ?>
              </td>
              <td colspan="2"><strong>Paid Amount: </strong><?php echo $payablesum; ?>
              </td>
              <td colspan="2"><strong>Pending Amount: </strong><?php echo $unpaidamount; ?>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: please put more complete code, from **<table>** tag beginning and its end

Answer (score 0):

try it (i don't test it yet, so tell me edit code if there is any typical mistake)

1. we just use one php block
2. instead collecting all of state values in single variable, we have our arrays which collects state of each name inside the separate index of their array
3. for each **voucher**, we have a table row  element and push it to an array in named_rows[$voucher['name']]
4. at last, we have another loop to print our tables, pleas read comments inside the code

---

```
<!-- you shoul use only one php block <?php ?> -->

<?php
    $paidcount = Array(); // use arrays instead to separate each value for only unique name
    $unpaidcount = Array();
    $unpaidamount = Array();
    $totalsum = Array();
    $payablesum = Array();
    $count = 1;
    $name_count = 0;
    // this array holds all of the rows of each table by "name"
    $named_rows = Array();
    // keep an instance of table for future use
    $table_tag_start = '
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Voucher</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Net Amount</th>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Issue Date</th>
      <th>Due Date</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>';
    $table_tag_end = '
  </tbody>
</table>';
    // now search and separate each name then create new table for each one
    foreach ($this->vouchers as $key => $voucher)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($voucher['name'], $named_rows)) {
            $named_rows[$voucher['name']] = new Array();
        }
        $totalsum[$voucher['name']] += $voucher['total'];
        $payablesum[$voucher['name']] += $voucher['payable'];
        if($voucher['paid']==1) {
            $paidcount[$voucher['name']] += $voucher['paid'];
        }
        else {
            $unpaidamount[$voucher['name']] = $voucher['payable'];
            $unpaidcount[$voucher['name']]++;
        }
        $row = '<tr>
            <td>' . ($count++) . '</td>
            <td>' . $voucher['id'] . '</td>
            <td>' . ucwords($voucher['name']) . '</td>
            <td>' . $voucher['total'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $voucher['payable'] . '</td>
            <td>' . date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $voucher['id_month'], 10)) . '</td>
            <td>' . $voucher['issue_date'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $voucher['due_date'] . '</td>
            <td>' . (($voucher['paid']==1)?'Paid':'Pending') . '</td>
            <td class="text-center"><a href="' . SITEURL . 'vouchersinfo/?action=voucherDetails&id_voucher=' . $voucher['id'] .'" title="View Voucher Details">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span></a></td>
        </tr>';
        array_push($named_rows[$voucher['name']], $row);
    }
    // for each name, stored in "$named_rows" create a new table and for each row inside "$named_rows[current_name]" create rows
    // when rows are ended, then generate the last row (sum displays) as a new special row, and close the table
    foreach ($named_rows as $key1 => $value1)
    {
        $output = $table_tag_start;
        foreach ($named_rows[$key1] as $value2)
        {
            $output .= $value2;
        }
        $output .= '<tr>
              <td colspan="2"><strong>Total Vouchers: </strong>'.(--$count).'</td>
              <td colspan="1"><strong>Received: </strong>'.$paidcount[$key1].'</td>
              <td colspan="1"><strong>Unpaid: </strong>'.$unpaidcount[$key1].'</td>
              <td colspan="2"><strong>Total Amount: </strong>'.$totalsum[$key1].'</td>
              <td colspan="2"><strong>Paid Amount: </strong>'.$payablesum[$key1].'</td>
              <td colspan="2"><strong>Pending Amount: </strong>'.$unpaidamount[$key1].'</td>
            </tr>';
        $output .= $table_tag_end;
        echo $output;
    }
?>
```